# how to make a button bigger than toolbar area in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing a chat app that supports iOS 8.0 and greater. I want to send a voice recording message, I have a button which I have added as a custom view to bar button item and added long press gesture. I need a circular button above toolbar area when the user long press the voice button. How can I do that?

[image: After the button is long press]

Comment: better to use a custom UIView

Comment: Put a `UIButton` above the toolbar.